# expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type

Tags: enums, pi

This is my first try at a method without input. Here is the code:

```
int factorial(int a)
{
    int i = 1, result = 1;

    while (i <= a)
    {
        result = result * i;

        i++;
    }

    return result;
}

int double_factorial(int a)
{
    int i = 2, result = 1;

    while (i <= a)
    {
        result = result * i;

        i = i + 2;
    }

    return result;
}
long double pi()
{
    unsigned long int n = 4294967295;
    unsigned long int i = 0;
    long double result = 0;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        result = result + (factorial(i) / double_factorial(2 * i + 1));

        i++;
    }

    long double pi = result * 2;

    return pi;
}

long double circumference_circle_input_radius(double r)
{
    long double C = 2.0 * pi * r; //error: 'pi' expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type.
}
```

When I try to use method "pi" in this, the error appeared. I dont understand what the error means, so it is quite hard to understand the problem and debug it.

Comment: Which language is it? What is the error?

Comment: language C++, but my teacher is kind of push us toward C in terms of style and syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pi` is a function, not a variable. To call it in an expression, you need to use parentheses:

```
long double C = 2.0 * pi() * r;
                        ^^
```

Without the parentheses, the compiler thinks you're trying to multiply *the function itself* by 2, which isn't an operation that makes any sense.